# How to ensure no singleton expansion in numpy is made

Tags: python, numpy

Coming from MATLAB to NumPy, the distinction between 2 dimensional array where one of the dimensions equalsl 1 to 1D array is annoying.

For example:

```
>>>import numpy as np
>>>x1 = np.array([[1],[2],[3]])
>>>x2 = np.array([1,2,3])
>>>x1.shape
(3, 1)
>>>x2.shape
(3,)
```

so when using element wise product I am getting 3X3 matrix:

```
>>>x1 * x2
array([[1, 2, 3],
       [2, 4, 6],
       [3, 6, 9]])
```

But what I really want is

```
>>>np.squeeze(x1) * x2
array([1, 4, 9])
```

Any other way of doing this besides calling `np.squeeze()` on each vector?

Comment: I don't think there's a simpler way; `np.squeeze` seems simple enough honestly. The reason it's this way is for less ambiguity, which I think many people favor. There are alternatives such as `x1.reshape(-1)` and `x1.flatten()` (assuming you are only working with 2 dimensions), but I doubt that's what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are getting is the result of broadcasting, which `numpy` implemented long before MATLAB.  Even Octave had it before MATLAB.

You have a (3,1) and a (3,).  A leading dimension is added to the lower dim, producing (1,3).  Together those broadcast to (3,3), and do the math.

If you could somehow turn off broadcasting (you can't), I'd expect incompatible dimensions error.

You want a (3,) result, so you have to somehow remove the trailing dimension of (3,1) - `squeeze`, `reshape` or `[:,0]` index do that.

In Octave:

```
>> x1 = [1;2;3];    # (3,1)
>> y1 = [1,2,3];    # (1,3)
>> x1 .* y1         # (3,3)
ans =

   1   2   3
   2   4   6
   3   6   9
```

From Octave docs:

> A note on terminology: “broadcasting” is the term popularized by the
>   Numpy numerical environment in the Python programming language.  In
>   other programming languages and environments, broadcasting may also be
>   known as *binary singleton expansion* (BSX, in MATLAB, and the origin of
>   the name of the ‘bsxfun’ function), *recycling* (R programming
>   language), *single-instruction multiple data* (SIMD), or *replication*.

Turn on a warning about Octave extensions:

```
>> warning ("on","Octave:language-extension")
>> x1 .* y1
warning: performing `product' automatic broadcasting
ans =

   1   2   3
   2   4   6
   3   6   9
```